# Webdriver-manager unsupportedClassError

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I updated the webdriver-manager with npm install -g webdriver-manager,then updated and then started,but I got the following error message:

```
webdriver-manager: using local installed version 12.0.6
[17:33:45] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\obw\IVO_Workspace\mui-cpi
n-lb-spa\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.31.exe -Dwebdriv
er.gecko.driver=C:\obw\IVO_Workspace\mui-cpin-lb-spa\node_modules\webdriver-mana
ger\selenium\geckodriver-v0.18.0.exe -jar C:\obw\IVO_Workspace\mui-cpin-lb-spa\n
ode_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.5.2.jar -por
t 4444
[17:33:45] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 4272
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 ba
d major version; class=org/openqa/grid/selenium/GridLauncherV3, offset=6
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:15
4)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:711)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:92)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1159)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:314
)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:594)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:743)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:711)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:325)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:494)

[17:33:46] I/start - Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1

C:\obw\IVO_Workspace\mui-cpin-lb-spa>
```

Please Hwelp me,I am so nervous and I will break it.

Comment: The error `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 ba
d major version` says it all. Update your `Java` version to the most latest release.

Comment: IS ur probel solved?

Comment: Yes,Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Java version and make it compatible with JRE.

For detail description follow this links:

**http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/07/javalangunsupportedclassversionerror.html**

It is actually simple - you need to install BOTH JRE / JDK with the same version.

JRE 6 -> JDK 6

JRE 7 -> JDK 7

And so on

or

Your java version should be equivalent or greater than JRE

Comment: glad to hear it